# How can I know reachability of A* algorithm on a graph?

Tags: algorithm

I got some data set of a graph.

then I have to get distance between city A and B.

How can I know reachability of route from A to B ?

do I have to search for all reachable cities with a*?

I think that needs so much time.

Comment: Are you looking only for reachability (is there a path from A to B) without the length of it? What is your heuristic function? Is it admissible? Is it monotonic?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if an arbitrary node is reachable from another arbitrary node, then yes, you will need to search the graph. Yes, this means you could end up traversing every node on the graph. Yes, if you have a huge number of nodes, it will be slow. Life is tough.

If you need to do many such reachability checks, it might be worth it to pre-process the graph, and store reachability information which can be used for faster lookups. That information will probably take a lot of space, though you could use secondary storage (i.e. hard drive).